# Want to cancel a 'Pending Erase' on iphone... Any suggestions?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

I lost my phone on vacation and activated 'Lost Mode' for a couple of days. The night before heading home I decided to do the Remote Erase ´cause I thought there's no way I'd get it back, I also called my carrier and canceled the data service on my number. The phone has been offline ever since but the hotel just called to say they found my phone at the spa and they are mailing it back to me. So I want to cancel the 'Pending Erase', all I care about is recovering all the pictures from that trip that I hadn't backed up on iCloud yet...
Will removing the device from my iCloud account work? 
And if I don't have service on the phone, will the 'Erase iPhone' command still go through when I turn it on? 
Please help! I have two days to figure this out

Comment: As long as you don't turn your phone on, you have all the time in the world :-)

Comment: I have just turned it off on iCloud, and then I tried giving it wifi. It still erased. And now it requires the activation....shit.

Answer (score 2):

> #### Cancel an erase
>
> If your device is offline, the remote erase happens the next time it is online. If you find the device before it is erased, you can cancel the request.
>
> 1. In Find My iPhone on iCloud.com, click All Devices, then select the device.
>
>    If you do not see All Devices, it is because you have already selected a device. Click the name of the current device in the centre of the toolbar to access the Devices list, then select a new device.
> 2. Click Stop Erase Request, then enter your Apple ID password.

https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/mmfc0ef36f/icloud