# Can I recall (cancel) the erase my iPhone command

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone, secure-erase

I had lost my iPhone, and I initiated the erase iPhone using iCloud. But, in the meanwhile, I found the iPhone. I am holding it in airplane mode, and it is still not wiped. I'm aware that if I turn on internet for it, it will probably start erasing all. I would love if I could cancel the erase command. Is this possible? Otherwise, I would just have to erase it, and back it up from iCloud backup. I would rather, not do any of that and just cancel the erase command. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for asking. In the past there was [no such cancel window of opportunity.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179188/) Sorry you didn’t catch it in time.